# How the size of ribosomes are calculated?

Tags: microbiology, ribosome

When I was studying microbiology, something didn't make sense to me. We all know ribosomes have two subunits; the large subunit and the small subunit. Such as for eukaryotic cells, the large subunit has 60 S (svedberg) and  small subunit has 40 S. When they combine with each other they are considered as 80 S. Why it is 80 S instead 100 S?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because Svedberg is not a measure of weight, but it is a measure of a relative sedimentation after centrifugation. 
"It is defined as the ratio of a particle's sedimentation velocity to the acceleration that is applied to it (causing the sedimentation)." 
The high number of S are correlated to the shape of the particles as well.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sedimentation_coefficient

Comment: @AhmetÖz If this answer [addressed your problem](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers), please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234) by clicking on the check mark/tick to the left of the answer, turning it green. This marks the question as resolved to your satisfaction, and awards [reputation](http://biology.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) both to you and the person who answered. If you have >= 15 reputation points, you may also upvote the answer if you wish. There is no obligation to do either.